# Cannot get PSVariable from Powershell Invoke method

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm running C# PowerShell code on a remote system and need to get the value of a local variable. PowerShell has a cmdlet named `Get-Variable` which I'm trying to use. This is my code for trying to fetch the relevant collection of PSVariables (which obviously should contain just one):

```
psShell.AddScript($"$text = 'someValue'");

psShell.Invoke();

psShell.Commands.Clear();

psShell.AddCommand("Get-Variable")
.AddParameter("Name", "text");

var v = psShell.Invoke<PSVariable>();
```

Problem is on the last line, I get the following exception:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.PSVariable" value of type "Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.PSVariable" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSVariable".
```

Anyone know how to solve this ?

Also, I know of the SessionStateProxy method mentioned on StackOverflow, but [as this post of mine shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132985/how-do-i-get-environment-variable-value-from-remote-powershell-c-sharp-code), it doesn't work for my scenario for some reason.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in PowerShell. I get the variable returned using a generic method. Have you tried setting `var v` to `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSVariable>`? See [Invoke<T>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_PowerShell_Invoke__1)

Comment: I meant changing `var` to `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSVariable>`.

Comment: While I haven't tried it, it should not help because using `var` automatically infers the correct data type .. that is it's own point!

Comment: I'm aware, I just wanted to to see if something strange was going on and declaring the object explicitly worked. You have an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When PowerShell remoting is involved, only a handful of well-known types deserialize with type fidelity, `System.Management.Automation.PSVariable` *not* being among them.

Instances of all other types deserialize as method-less *emulations* of the original objects, as `[psobject]` instances with properties containing static copies of the original property values.
In PowerShell, these instances report their type name as the original type name prefixed with `Deserialized.`
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for background information.

The simplest way to handle such objects is via the DLR:

```
dynamic v = psShell.Invoke();
```

Then you can access properties as usual (albeit with runtime binding), e.g.,  `v.Name`.